# Script return summary of exit codes

Tags: command-line-interface

I use this command for test my html pages for errors:

```
find . -iname '*html' -type f -print -exec /usr/local/bin/tidy -q -e {} \;
```

And I want to get exit code > 0 if any errors was founded by tidy.

find always return me 0.

Is there any way to sums exit code from tidy, and return it from find or any other wrapper script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM_FAILS=0

for FILE in $(find . -iname '*.html' -type f -print); do
  /usr/local/bin/tidy -q -e ${FILE}

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    ((NUM_FAILS++))
  fi

done

if [ ${NUM_FAILS} -gt 0 ]; then
  echo -e "There were ${NUM_FAILS} failed files."
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Explanation: You'll want to loop through the results of the `find` command, run `tidy`, then increment a counter if an error is found (I assume `tidy` will generate a non-zero return code on error).

Once you've looped through the files, if there are any errors, you can `exit 1`, and it's always good practice to explicitly `exit 0` if things completed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
find . -iname '*html' -type f \( -exec tidy -q -e {} \; -o -print \)
```

This would only print out filenames for which `tidy` exited with an error code.  You could use `-fprint` to collect the filenames in a file:

```
find . -iname '*html' -type f \( -exec tidy -q -e {} \; -o -fprint files_with_errors \)
```

These constructs take advantage of the fact that `-exec` is a boolean expression that returns true or false depending on the success of the command; the `-o` flag is a boolean `OR`, so this reads:

*find all entries that match `*html` AND that are files AND ( for which tidy returns true OR print the filename)*

Comment: Much more eloquent solution than mine, +1 :)